Need help why my Azure function is not logging Trace, Debug or Information to Insights. it does log Warn, Error and Critical
So I am trying to get my logging to work. Below is my Azure function code
    [Function("TestLogging")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        // Logging at different levels
        _logger.LogTrace("This is a Trace log.");
        _logger.LogDebug("This is a Debug log.");
        _logger.LogInformation("This is an Information log.");
        _logger.LogWarning("This is a Warning log.");
        _logger.LogError("This is an Error log.");
        _logger.LogCritical("This is a Critical log.");

The issue I am having when executing it from Azure function Code + Test I can see that _logger.LogInformation is working.

Also when I watching the Logs it also works correctly as shown below

The issue when I go to Application Insights and look at the LOG there I only see the following. In other words I am not seeing LogTrace, LogDebug or LogInformation

My host.json file is shown below
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information",
        "Function.TestLogging": "Trace"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function.TestLogging": "Trace"
    }
  }
}


Your host.json sets the log-level to Information, yes - but your screenshots show Verbose-level messages being logged, which shouldn't be happening due to the level set in your host.json.

What is the version of your app?


The issue when I go to Application Insights and look at the LOG there I only see the following. In other words I am not seeing LogTrace, LogDebug or LogInformation

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack .NET 8.0
The below code and configuration is worked and getting all the logs in application insights which i mentioned in code.
** Function code:**
 public class Function1
 {
     private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

     public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     [Function("Function1")]
     public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
     {
         _logger.LogTrace("this is Trace log");
         _logger.LogDebug("this is Debug log");
         _logger.LogWarning("this is Warning log");
         _logger.LogError("this is Error log");
         _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
         return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
     }
 }


host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"

      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
        {
            console.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


Output:


